# Ext JS create custom component(class)

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I want to create a custom component(container) that would contain other components (labels, buttons,...).

I would like to create some kind of a class so I would be able to create multiple instances of this component but with different params. Somekind of constructor. These params would set the labels and button options.

I am using Sencha Architect, so I am wondering is this possible and how it could be done?

Answer (score 2):

Via ExtJS code you just can use the Ext Class System:

```
Ext.define('MyOwnView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    constructor: function () {
        // ... your code
    }
});
```

To achieve this via Architect GUI, follow this guide (with screenshots):
http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/creating_an_application/working_with_classes.html

Comment: How can I make the views inside class members so I can set them value via constructor??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question :( Could you describe it different?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ext.define` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-define) to define your new class prototype as follows:

```
Ext.define('My.app.Panel', {
     extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
     requires: [
         'My.app.PanelPart2',
         'My.app.PanelPart3'
     ]

     constructor: function (config) {
         this.callParent(arguments); // calls Ext.panel.Panel's constructor
         //...
     }
 });
```